# How to push output file to MySQL db within Alteryx Designer?

Tags: mysql, alteryx

I have a scheduled Alteryx workflow running everyday which outputs csv file. I would like to automate the command to push this file into the mysql db like this:

[As is] Current workflow outputs the file
[To be added] load data local infile 'path-to-file' into table `table` lines terminated by '\r\n' ignore 1 lines;

Is this possible? How can I setup the workflow?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the workflow, then you can add another Output tool and output directly to the mysql without going through the CSV.

If you only have access to the csv, you can set up a workflow that reads the csv and outputs to the mysql db.

Comment: Thanks for guidance, how can I do it?